# parsing unamed object in external JSON file

Tags: javascript

I really tried to find something.

**Statements:**
There's a `kog.json file`(that i don't have access to)

it contains something like

```
{gold:"or not",
mine:"or hot",
Paris:"i hate one"}
```

It's kind of *unnamed object*.

What do i need is to get data of Paris and put it somewhere, just as a simple `string`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

First, return the kog.json file with `dataType: text`(text/plain)
This returned data in the json file as string.

```
 var data = '{gold:"or not",\r\nmine:"o...",\r\nParis:"i hate one"}';
```

Now the unwanted *\r\n* was removed (line-break)

```
var formattedData = data.replace(/\r\n/g, '');
```

Lastly an unholy eval was performed like this.

```
eval("var objLiteral = " + formattedData);
```

so that I could get Paris like this

```
console.log(objLiteral["Paris"]);
```

JavaScript Snippet

```
var url = "/WebFormsDemo/Samples/kog.json";
window.onload = function () {
    var filePath = url;
    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.open("GET", filePath, false);
    xmlhttp.send(null);
    var data = xmlhttp.responseText;
    //removing the line breaks in your text
    var formattedData = data.replace(/\r\n/g, '');
    eval("var objLiteral = " + formattedData);
    console.log(objLiteral["Paris"]);
};
```

jQuery Snippet

```
$(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        //force to handle it as text
        dataType: "text",
        success: function (data) {
            //removing the line breaks in your text
            var formattedData = data.replace(/\r\n/g, '');
            eval("var objLiteral = " + formattedData);
            console.log(objLiteral["Paris"]);
        }
    });

});
```

P.S: You should really be changing the format of "kog.json". Its invalid JSON.

Comment: Thx, a lot. As i said, i don't have access to that file :D
Kind of... at all

Answer (score 1):

[JSON.parse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) might be what you're looking for if you have a way to get that JSON string.

Something like..

```
var data = '{"gold":"or not", "mine":"or hot", "Paris":"i hate one"}';
var object = JSON.parse(data);
console.log(object.Paris);
```

Comment: I don't have access to json file.
That way i'm unable to just change everything to look good.

Comment: `eval('var object = {gold:"or not",mine:"or hot",Paris:"i hate one"};');` would work but it's kind of a hacky way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

One way will be to use parseJSON of the jQuery library. See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aupbnog7/)

```
var data = '{"gold":"or not", "mine":"or hot", "Paris":"i hate one"}';
var jsonObject = $.parseJSON(data);
alert(jsonObject.Paris);
```

Comment: notice no quotes over "gold/mine/Paris"
It doesn't work w/o quotes, in addition i have to import file.

Comment: Ok, I thaught you just forgot them as you said "something like this"